# Why isn't the rvm installed version of Rails working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Still struggling with a pernicious bug in my rvm environment:

```
    rails -v
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0) among 0 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rails:22
```

This looks like a path problem, because it is looking in the default Ruby that comes with Debian.  Here is my path:

/home/caseyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/home/caseyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/bin:/home/caseyr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/home/caseyr/.rvm/bin:/home/caseyr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games

Yet, this is the default Ruby version:

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [i686-linux]
```

Could it be that Rails has its own, separate path? Don't know, but this is instructive:

```
which rails
/usr/bin/rails
```

which seems to totally ignore rvm, since the path should be pointing to ruby 2.0.0. How can this be?

The gem environment seems ok:

```
    $ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.0
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-02-24 patchlevel 0) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/caseyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/caseyr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/caseyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/caseyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0
     - /home/caseyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/

--as well as the rvm one:
<BS>$ rvm info

ruby-2.0.0-p0:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux beta 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Sun Sep 23 09:49:36 UTC 2012 i686 GNU/Linux"
    system:      "debian/6.0.7/i386"
    bash:        "/usr/local/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.19.6 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "8 days 17 minutes 26 seconds ago"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.0.0p0"
    date:         "2013-02-24"
    platform:     "i686-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2013-02-24 revision 39474"
    full_version: "ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [i686-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/caseyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0"
    ruby:         "/home/caseyr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/home/caseyr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home/caseyr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home/caseyr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home/caseyr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/caseyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/home/caseyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/bin:/home/caseyr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/home/caseyr/.rvm/bin:/home/caseyr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/caseyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/caseyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0:/home/caseyr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/caseyr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0"
    IRBRC:        "/home/caseyr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

I realize there are similar questions like this have already been answered (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622467/after-installing-ruby-gems-running-the-new-gem-returns-could-not-find-errors)), but have still not found one that has let me understand what's really going on (after several removals, re-installs, etc...)

Any help will be much appreciated; would really like to get Rails working again...

--rixter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first see which rubies are installed using rvm

```
rvm list
```

It will display ruby versions installed.

Then make use of `rvm --default use ruby-2.0.0-p0`

then create gemset using `rvm gemset create gemset1`

```
rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p0@gemset1

gem install rails -v rails_version
```

after installing try `rails -v`