# rake db:create error in postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I'm using ubuntu. For my rails application, after `bundle install`, i typed the `rake db:create` then there's show the following error:

```
/home/imtiaz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'rake' (>= 0) among 0 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /home/imtiaz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
    from /home/imtiaz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in `gem'
    from /home/imtiaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
    from /home/imtiaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/imtiaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I've tried `which ruby` `which rake` `which bundle` command. That gives me the answer:

```
/home/imtiaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/bin/bundle  for `which bundle`
/home/imtiaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/rake for `which rake`
/home/imtiaz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby for `which ruby`
```

**what can i do now???**

Comment: maybe this similar question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622467/after-installing-ruby-gems-running-the-new-gem-returns-could-not-find-errors (seems you are using rvm too)

Comment: provide `bundle show rake` please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

`bundle exec rake db:create`

Which will use the copy of `rake` that you installed with the bundle.  This is true for any bin files that are part of the bundle.